# Why Window Outlook Rest API does not support Android

Tags: android, outlook

From Windows Live website , they suggest use Outlook REST APIs instead Live Connect APIs

> The Live Connect APIs are deprecated. We recommend that you use the
>   Outlook REST APIs to build your solutions.

[image]

But seem they did not support for Android OS. May I know the reason why Window does not support for Android ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do.  See:  https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-SDK-Android

Also-  these are REST apis.  That means they work by querying an HTTP server.  That means they work for anything, even if they don't provide a nice SDK you can always query the server directly.